# Multiple mutexes for multiple variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399719/):

I have some lengthy assignments to different variables that are shared between threads. Does it make sense to split those assignments in single scopes to prevent a single lock_guard to occupy all variables?

The next thread can use the first variable if the previous thread moved on to the second scope.

My guess is that it depends on the complexity of the called function. If you have just an assignment it is surely faster than having a second lock_guard locking/unlocking another mutex.

**Pseudocode**

```
// all used variables beside the lock_guards are created and initialized somewhere else

// do something ...

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut0);
    shared_var0 = SomeFunctionTakingSameTime0();  
}

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut1);
    shared_var1 = SomeFunctionTakingSameTime1();  
}

// do this again or other stuff ...
```

What may be advantages or disadvantages for this type of code structure?

Comment: Useful research term: Priority Inversion

Comment: As well as @user4581301 useful research term, you shouldn't hold locks for long. If possible, run the function outside the lock to a local and then assign to the shared variable inside the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I assume that `SomeFunctionTakingSameTime0()` is somewhat a time-consuming function. But the only way you interact with the shared variables is the assignment. Therefore, it may be better to do something like this:

```
auto temp = SomeFunctionTakingSameTime0();
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut0);
    shared_var0 = std::move(temp);  
}
```

Since you gave two different mutexes `mut0` and `mut1` for the locks, the best thing you can do is to acquire them separately.

Comment: This assumes the assignment of `temp` to `shared_var` is not a costly operation of its own, taking some time to perform the copy.  If the variable supports move semantics, use that to reduce complexity/overhead.

Comment: I think this works if no other shared variable is used by 
 SomeFunctionTakingSameTime0() ? If the move semantic is lightweight. I would execute the functions to temp variables and move both in a single lock_guard scope?

Comment: @KabCode Sorry? What do you mean? Does `SomeFunctionTakingSameTime0` need to access any shared variable?

Comment: @ L. F. This was just an additional thought on your answer. As my initial question  state the functions need no access to any shared variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to split those assignments in single scopes to prevent a single lock_guard to occupy all variables?

True. Indeed, your intuition is correct.

> What may be advantages or disadvantages for this type of code structure?

However, this kind of situation cannot be predicted with a very limited snippet of code. The better suggestion here is to perform some benchmarks.

Some important aspects I personally would take into account:

- type of `shared_var0`?
- time to lock the mutex > time to complete `SomeFunctionTakingSameTime1`?

As you said if your functions `SomeFunctionTakingSameTime0` and `SomeFunctionTakingSameTime1` will take a *considerable* amount of time, then splitting in two different scopes could help to maximize the throughput.

In general, the *critical section* (i.e., the scope in which you hold the lock) should be as short as possible.

Of course, like everything, there is a tradeoff. The `lock`/`unlock` operations are not free.

```
int shared; 
lock(mutex);
shared = 1;
unlock(mutex);

lock(mutex);
shared = 2;
unlock(mutex);
```

Of course, this a silly example. But it shows the critical aspect into the locking acquisition operation.
The assignment operation in the example is so much cheaper than locking the mutex twice!
Moreover, it will prevent some compiler optimizations (the assignment `shared = 1` can be completely removed -from the semantic point of view-).

To conclude, if the type of `shared_var0` and `shared_var1` is fundamental (`int`, `float`, etc) you could even consider the possibility to store them into an `std::atomic` and completely avoid mutexes.